# Commands from packages installed with yarn not found?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, yarnpkg

I installed `vue-cli` globally with `yarn`, but `vue` is giving a "command not found" error. Why did this happen, and how do I fix this?

Some interesting debug info:

```
$ yarn global list
yarn global v1.7.0
info "qbrt@0.2.5" has binaries:
   - qbrt
info "vue-cli@2.9.6" has binaries:
   - vue
   - vue-init
   - vue-list
info "webpack@4.16.0" has binaries:
   - webpack
Done in 0.56s.
$ ls $(yarn global bin)
$
```

As you can see, my binaries directory seems to be empty...

Comment: You should use tag yarnpkg insteal of yarn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that the binaries were ending up somewhere else.

```
$ yarn global bin
/home/username/.npm-packages/bin
$ ls ~/.yarn/bin
acorn   errno        handlebars  _metalsmith   rimraf       sha.js        uglifyjs  vue-init  win-fork
atob    esparse      json5       miller-rabin  seek-bunzip  sshpk-conv    uid       vue-list  win-line-endings
cake    esvalidate   js-yaml     mkdirp        seek-table   sshpk-sign    uuid      webpack   win-spawn
coffee  extract-zip  metalsmith  qbrt          semver       sshpk-verify  vue       which
```

Odd, but adding `~/.yarn/bin` to my `$PATH` fixed it.